# Viewstate decoder for asp.net 2

Tags: viewstate, decode, fiddler, decoder

I need to decode a viewstate value in asp.net framework 2.
How can I do that?

I tried to use Fiddler2 extention but it didn't help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly `didn't it help` you? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is simply `base64` encoded value. Here is option [Fritz Onion](http://mercury.pluralsight.com/tools.aspx). You probably will not be able to directly modify the `ViewState` (i.e. outside of code) because ASP.NET has checks in place to specifically ensure that nothing has tampered with the `ViewState`. See the [EnableViewStateMAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx) setting for more.

Comment: Fritz' link is dead =/

Comment: The https://codeutil.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/asp-net-view-state-decoders/ list a few other decoders, some of them are still available, e.g. https://www.binaryfortress.com/aspnet-viewstate-helper/